# Mysql query INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE adds new entry even when it shouldn't

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql2

My question is quite simple but it's been driving me crazy the last day and I can't find any clear, concise info that relates exactly to my problem. I have the following query

```
INSERT INTO people_names SET lastname = ?, firstname = ?, lifespan = ? 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), lastname = VALUES(lastname), firstname = VALUES(firstname), lifespan = VALUES(lifespan)
```

Basically what I want it to do is to insert the data (which comes from a form and is gathered correctly - that part works) and if the person already exists in the table, just update the row so that I can get the id via LAST_INSERT_ID, and otherwise create a new entry for the person in the table (if that name and lifespan doesnt already exist). The person has a many-to-many relationship to other stuff so I need to get its ID regardless if it was inserted or detected as already existing, to put in another table that handles the many-to-many relationships. The "id" in the people_names table is an autoincrement primary key.

However, lets say I already have a person in the table people_names which is lastname "Doe", firstname "John", lifespan "1900-1999", and then I enter the same data in the form and send it to the query, a new entry is created in the same table with exactly the same info ("Doe", "John", "1900-1999") instead of updating the already existing one.

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You have the incorrect syntax in `INSERT` query.

Your SQL Query should look like:

```
            INSERT INTO
                table (field_1, field_2)
            VALUES
                (?, ?)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                field_2 = VALUES(field_2)
```

Comment: Oh! I forgot to say that I'm using the mysql2 package for nodejs, so the query is executed like this: `let query = 'INSERT INTO people_names SET lastname = ?, firstname = ?, lifespan = ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), lastname = VALUES(lastname), firstname = VALUES(firstname), lifespan = VALUES(lifespan)';
let data = [lastName, firstName, lifeSpan];
await connection.promise().query(query, data,);`

Comment: so? is it still not working? have you tried my SQL query?